# How to select parent div element with js

Tags: javascript, html, select

This is my html code:

```
<div class="w-grid-list">
<article class="product_cat-19">
    <div class="w-grid-item-h">
        <a class="w-grid-item-anchor" href="#"></a>
            <div class="w-vwrapper">
                <div class="w-post-elm">
                    <a href="">
                        title1
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="w-post-elm">
                    <span class="w-post-elm-before">color code : </span>
                    <span class="sku">228</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-html">color</div>
            </div>  
    </div>
</article>
<article class="product_cat-19">
    <div class="w-grid-item-h">
        <a class="w-grid-item-anchor" href="#"></a>
            <div class="w-vwrapper">
                <div class="w-post-elm">
                    <a href="">
                        title2
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="w-post-elm">
                    <span class="w-post-elm-before">color code : </span>
                    <span class="sku">229</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-html">color</div>
            </div>  
    </div>
</article>
</div>

<div class="owl-stage">
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 204px;">
    <article class="product_cat-18">
        <div class="w-grid-item-h">
            <div class="w-hwrapper">
                <div class="w-vwrapper">
                    <div class="w-post-elm">
                        <a href="#"></a></div>
                            <h2 class="w-post-elm">
                                <a href="#">title of product1</a>
                            </h2>
                    <div class="w-post-elm">
                        <span class="Price-amount">140<span class="Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 204px;">
    <article class="product_cat-19">
        <div class="w-grid-item-h">
            <div class="w-hwrapper">
                <div class="w-vwrapper">
                    <div class="w-post-elm">
                        <a href="#"></a></div>
                            <h2 class="w-post-elm">
                                <a href="#">title of product2</a>
                            </h2>
                    <div class="w-post-elm">
                        <span class="Price-amount">120<span class="Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
</div>
```

And I want to hide(style display:none) Div Element just with "owl-item" class which it has "article" tag with "product_cat-19" class.

my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    // get the heading from the first article
    const product_cat_19 = document.querySelector('.product_cat-19');
    // get its parent, the current article
    const currentArticle = product_cat_19.parentNode.style.display='none';
</script>
```

this code can not hide "owl-item" class. but hide div with "w-grid-list" class.
is there any way to do this with css only or js need?
I searched on Google and found only solutions to solve this problem with JavaScript that didn't work properly.
any one can help me to edit my code?

Comment: Let me know if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelector()` will match only for the first occurance it finds. You need `querySelectorAll()` to go through all elements and then check if the parents has (or not) the class you look for :

example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzXQeyN

```js
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('.product_cat-19')) {
  var dady = e.parentNode;
  if (dady.classList.contains("owl-item")) {
    dady.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="w-grid-list">
  <article class="product_cat-19">
    <div class="w-grid-item-h">
      <a class="w-grid-item-anchor" href="#"></a>
      <div class="w-vwrapper">
        <div class="w-post-elm">
          <a href="">
                        title1
                    </a>
        </div>
        <div class="w-post-elm">
          <span class="w-post-elm-before">color code : </span>
          <span class="sku">228</span>
        </div>
        <div class="w-html">color</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="product_cat-19">
    <div class="w-grid-item-h">
      <a class="w-grid-item-anchor" href="#"></a>
      <div class="w-vwrapper">
        <div class="w-post-elm">
          <a href="">
                        title2
                    </a>
        </div>
        <div class="w-post-elm">
          <span class="w-post-elm-before">color code : </span>
          <span class="sku">229</span>
        </div>
        <div class="w-html">color</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 204px;">
    <article class="product_cat-18">
      <div class="w-grid-item-h">
        <div class="w-hwrapper">
          <div class="w-vwrapper">
            <div class="w-post-elm">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <h2 class="w-post-elm">
              <a href="#">title of product1</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="w-post-elm">
              <span class="Price-amount">140<span class="Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>    
  
  <!-- will be hidden -->
  <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 204px;">
  <!-- because of this child -->
    <article class="product_cat-19">
      <div class="w-grid-item-h">
        <div class="w-hwrapper">
          <div class="w-vwrapper">
            <div class="w-post-elm">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <h2 class="w-post-elm">
              <a href="#">title of product2</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="w-post-elm">
              <span class="Price-amount">120<span class="Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

product2 's parent is hidden, if this is what you looked for. there can be many, it will hide every `.owl-item` holding a direct child with the class `.product_cat-19`.

---

if you want to hide any parent container if it has not the `.w-grid-list` ,

same way check the class then  *`if(okay){leave it} else { hide it}`*

```js
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('.product_cat-19')) {
 var dady = e.parentNode;
  if (dady.classList.contains("w-grid-list")) {}
  else {
  dady.style.display="none"; 
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="w-grid-list">
  <article class="product_cat-19">
    <div class="w-grid-item-h">
      <a class="w-grid-item-anchor" href="#"></a>
      <div class="w-vwrapper">
        <div class="w-post-elm">
          <a href="">
                        title1
                    </a>
        </div>
        <div class="w-post-elm">
          <span class="w-post-elm-before">color code : </span>
          <span class="sku">228</span>
        </div>
        <div class="w-html">color</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="product_cat-19">
    <div class="w-grid-item-h">
      <a class="w-grid-item-anchor" href="#"></a>
      <div class="w-vwrapper">
        <div class="w-post-elm">
          <a href="">
                        title2
                    </a>
        </div>
        <div class="w-post-elm">
          <span class="w-post-elm-before">color code : </span>
          <span class="sku">229</span>
        </div>
        <div class="w-html">color</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 204px;">
    <article class="product_cat-18">
      <div class="w-grid-item-h">
        <div class="w-hwrapper">
          <div class="w-vwrapper">
            <div class="w-post-elm">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <h2 class="w-post-elm">
              <a href="#">title of product1</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="w-post-elm">
              <span class="Price-amount">140<span class="Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>    
  
  <!-- will be hidden -->
  <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 204px;">
  <!-- because of this child -->
    <article class="product_cat-19">
      <div class="w-grid-item-h">
        <div class="w-hwrapper">
          <div class="w-vwrapper">
            <div class="w-post-elm">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <h2 class="w-post-elm">
              <a href="#">title of product2</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="w-post-elm">
              <span class="Price-amount">120<span class="Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can grab the element, both, with JavaScript & CSS like so:

**JavaScript:**

```
const el = document.querySelectorAll('.owl-item .product_cat-19');
el[0].style.display = 'none';
```

**CSS:**

```
.owl-item > .product_cat-19 {
   display: none;
 }
```

Comment: thanks. I use your code :  '.owl-item .product_cat-19' in my js code.